# How data backup is handled in production via Docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I've a following Docker file that runs a MySQL image.

```
version: '3'

services:

  mysql:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    container_name: "mysql"
    ports:
      - "6603:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./assets/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      MYSQL_USER: mysql
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
```

I'm running it locally but I've concerns before I go in production.

How the data backup occurs? Shall I keep committing container to an image?

I'm new to Docker so wondering how things are handled in production when it comes to database deployed via Docker.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think you should commit container to an image. Data is something managed by the container but it is not "part" of db container. If you want to store data between container restarts you should use volumes - this way you will be able to save data on your host volume and run more `mysql` cointainers with this volume, sharing same data. How to use volumes with `mysql` image is described in their [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) - section `Where to Store Data`.

And also if you wanted to make dumps of your database it is also described in the documentation in section `Creating database dumps`.

In case you are running more db containers and you want to make dumps you should automate this process somehow for example as Jenkins job that has access to your containers, or some scripts run as cron job on your docker host - it all depends what tools you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You should add volumes to contain the actual db files. You currently have only the schema, for some reason, and when your container will go down, your data will be lost. 
After adding the volumes as persistent, you could use standard backup method, such as a cron job.